# Extract Only Certain Named Entities From Tokens

Tags: python, nlp, token, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Quick question (hopefully). Is it possible for me to get the named entities of the tokens except for the ones with CARDINAL label (The label is 397). Here is my code below:

```
spacy_model = spacy.load('en-core-web-lg')
f = open('temp.txt')
tokens = spacy_model(f.read())
named_entities = tokens.ents #Except where named_entities.label = 397
```

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand that I could filter out the Cardinal entities when I'm using it, but I'm going to be looping through these entities quite a bit, so I don't want to be inefficient.

Comment: Why not just use `named_entities = [t for t in tokens.ents if t.label_ != 'CARDINAL']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the entities using list comprehension:

```py
named_entities = [t for t in tokens.ents if t.label_ != 'CARDINAL']
```

Here is a test:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
tokens = nlp('The basket costs $10. I bought 6.')
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in tokens.ents])
# => [('10', 'MONEY'), ('6', 'CARDINAL')]
print([t for t in tokens.ents if t.label_ != 'CARDINAL'])
# => [10]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! I guess the object has to originally be a list right? I don't think this would work with the tokens. Like if I wanted to filter out only the tokens that had like token.text == 'this' for example this wouldn't work because tokens is a Doc object, and not a list

Comment: @A.Boy `tokens.ents` is a list, and you can filter it as any other list. Just each item is a token, with all the properties that you can check.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to filter tokens, the Doc object, this trick wouldn't work, right? Is there a way to filter out token objects before I get to the ents list?

Comment: @A.Boy I think you could use `[t for t in tokens if t.ent_type_ != 'CARDINAL']`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was getting my issue mixed up. My issue was that once I had it in list form I couldn't pickle it, because the tokens are just views of the Doc (I wanted to store them for later). I've come to learn this is not possible due to Spacy's limitations.